# No puedo enviar datos por POST con GuzzleHttp PHP

Tags: php, http

Espero puedan ayudarme,

Tengo 2 servidores uno con mi ERP y la BD y otro donde tengo mi página web, normalmente desde mi web consulto la BD del ERP y siempre he usado GuzzleHttp para extraer la información, por lo tanto, GuzzleHttp solo lo tengo instalado en mi servidor de la página web.

Hasta ahora las consultas las realizaba mediante GET y los parámetros los enviaba por URL, ahora necesito realizar la misma consulta, pero en lugar de enviar los parámetros por GET (o URL) los quiero enviar mediante POST.

El detalle es que, en el servidor donde tengo mi ERP no recibo los parámetros cuando son enviados por POST solo cuando los envió por URL.

Código que tengo en el servidor de mi página web

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "inc/datosconexion.php";
    
$client = new Client(['base_uri'=>BASE_URI]);
$url= 'url/demo';
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
      'debug' => fopen('C:\wamp64\www\cxp\eje.txt', 'w'),
    'form_params' => [
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ],
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

Código que esta en el servidor de la BD

```
<?php
var_dump( $_POST['form_params']);
echo $_REQUEST['field_name'];
echo $_REQUEST['email'];
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Cuando consulto del servidor de la página web al servidor del ERP obtengo el siguiente resultado.

```
NULL array(0) { } array(0) { } jaimeNULL NULL NULL
```

Debug.

> ```
> * Found bundle for host **********[serially]
> * Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host ***************
> * Connected to********** (**********) port 80 (#0)
> > GET /url/demo/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: ************
> User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.70.0 PHP/7.3.21
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> < Date: Thu, 24 Feb 2022 03:53:36 GMT
> < Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
> < Content-Length: 51
> < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> < 
> * Connection #0 to host ************ left intact
> tion #0 to host ******** left intact
> ```

Comment: Pero que es lo pasa? Los dumps no mi explica. ¿Es un problema de colisión? Explica un poco mas. No veo pregunta.

Comment: Esa sintaxis `$client->request` no la veo en la documentacion de guzzlephp. [Revisala](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/guzzle4/clients.html)

Comment: Aquí está la documentación para solicitar por POST https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/6.5/quickstart.html#post-form-requests

Comment: Vale, mea culpa, yo estaba mirando la documentacion de la version 4, que era distinta. Pues ni idea, como no sea que te sobran un par de comas (una despues de testpassword y otra al cerrar ese array, pero no creo que sea eso si no te da error de nada... aunque lo curioso es el debug ese que muestras, donde pone esto: `> GET /url/demo/ HTTP/1.1` ... ¿quieres decir que estas ejecutando el script correcto con post?)

Comment: Hola @masterguru, si, las comas no son el problema, también me causa mucho ruido que el debug me dice que estoy haciendo una petición GET, en la documentación no indica nada https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/6.5/request-options.html#debug

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba de tu código instalando el guzzle 7 (porque soporta php 7.2.5 en adelante y mi version es al 8.0.15) y cambiando tan solo la url por una de mi servidor local, y me funciona bien: NULL
test@gmail.comarray(3) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "test@gmail.com"
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Test user"
  ["password"]=>
  string(12) "testpassword"
}
array(3) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "test@gmail.com"
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Test user"
  ["password"]=>
  string(12) "testpassword"
}  (bueno, en la BASE_URI tambien le puse mi localhost, no se para que sirve tampoco)

Comment: Y esto es el debug: *   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /guzz.php HTTP/1.1M
Host: localhostM
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/7M
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedM
Content-Length: 59M

Comment: Como ves, alli si que sale el POST... debes estar invocando otro script por alguna razon en tu código, ejecutalo a pelo como yo desde terminal o actualiza tu guzzle a la 7